# where are the dictionary files stored in visual studio

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am trying to make an application which checks whether a word is a valid dictionary word.

```
NetSpell.SpellChecker.Dictionary.WordDictionary oDict = new NetSpell.SpellChecker.Dictionary.WordDictionary(); 

oDict.DictionaryFile = "en-US.dic"; 
oDict.Initialize(); // file not found exception
string wordToCheck = "door";
NetSpell.SpellChecker.Spelling oSpell = new NetSpell.SpellChecker.Spelling(); 

oSpell.Dictionary = oDict; 
if(oSpell.TestWord(wordToCheck))
{
   //Word exist in dictionary
    ...
}
```

I have tried giving all possible file locations like ".\en-US.dic" to "C:\Program Files\IIS Express\en-US.dic" but i still get file not found exception. Can anyone help me in figuring where the file actually is.

Comment: do you mean English dictionary for spell check?

Comment: @BugFinder Hi, I don't think this is a duplicate for the post you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

When you install netSpell using nuget a new folder is created by the name 'Packages'. All the .dic (dictionary) files are stored in that folder.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a relative path using `Server.MapPath`:

If the file `en-US.dic` is in your **root directory**, use:

```
oDict.DictionaryFile = Server.MapPath("en-US.dic");
```

If the file `en-US.dic` is nested **under some other directory**, use:

```
oDict.DictionaryFile = Server.MapPath("/SomeDirectory/en-US.dic");
```

Comment: Hi @Chris, Please see that he mentioned "C:\Program Files\IIS Express..." That is how I figured out he is running a web server.

Comment: Ah yes. Well spotted. :)

Comment: @Chris - Thanks buddy :)